# How to change list contents within another WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have two WPF windows, one with a list and another one which is supposed to change the contents of that list. How could I do that?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: If one of the windows is a Dialog, you could just pass the Datacontext of the Main window to the dialog and update after closing. 
If both windows are open at the same time. I personally like to use a static class, or more globally central object to act as a mediator. If this becomes a common pattern I would probably try to solve it in a better way, but if it is a one off, I would just use something central.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest example**

[image]

The model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    internal class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
            AddStuff = new RelayCommand(() => Collection.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        }

        public RelayCommand AddStuff { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; } = new();
    }
}
```

The command:

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, () => true)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute();
        }

        public void Execute(object? parameter)
        {
            _execute();
        }

        public event EventHandler? CanExecuteChanged;
    }
}
```

App.xaml: the model is shared

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="Window1.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:Model x:Key="Model" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Window 1:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Class="WpfApp1.Window1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{StaticResource Model}">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window 1:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class Window1
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            new Window2().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Window 2:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window2" Height="450" Width="800" DataContext="{StaticResource Model}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Whatever" Command="{Binding AddStuff}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Window 2:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class Window2
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example by keeping a reference to the window to be updated from the other window, or get the reference to that window using the `Application.Current.Windows` property:

```
var listBoxInWindow1 = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window1>()?
    .FirstOrDefault()?.listBox1;
```

**Window1.xaml:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox1" .... />
```

Comment: @ItsDano: Did you try this?